# Android webview loading css from assets, but not js

Tags: android, android-webview

Using Android Studio and avd emulator. css defintely loading, js will execute from within head or attached to body tag, but not from external file in assets.

**My MainActivity:**

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    setContentView(webview);
```

**My html head:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
<script src="jquery.mobile.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="my.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

**Test JS (no jquery) that executes in head but not in external my.js:**

```
 function var1() {
  document.getElementById('jstest').innerHTML = 'hi';
}

window.onload = var1;
```

**My Current sentiment:**

Charlie Brown.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to jquery.min.js and getting rid of the mobile version has resolved everything. It probably sent the entire js into tilt, but the inline was processing first.